# Upload image into MS Azure with Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently working on the VueJs framework, and I need to connect my project to the Azure. But I don't know how? I used before the (firebase) is it with the same technique where we add a configuration for the storage inside the project?

Currently, I created I new blob and container in Azure, and I got a saskey and the primary/secondary paths .. but I am not sure what is the next step?

Also in my VueJs project, I add this code:

```
    var sasKey = '....'; //The code from the Azure
    var blobUri = '...'; //The path
    var blobService = AzureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sasKey).withFilter(new AzureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());

      blobService.createBlockBlobFromText('ContainerName', 'BlobName', data,  function(error, result, response){
      if (error) {
          console.log('Upload filed, open browser console for more detailed info.');
          console.log(error);
      } else {
         console.log('Upload successfully!');
      }
    });
```

To clarify my question, I am a beginner in using both Vue.js and Azure. I need to know what is the correct steps to help me for successfully uploading an image to Azure storage.

In Addition, is it possible to add security headers? like what we do in Axios? for example to check the content-length, content-type, ... etc.

When I run the program, it always prints:

```
Upload filed, open browser console for more detailed info. 
Error: XHR error
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror
```

Answer (score 1):

First we need to allow CORS of Azure storage, we can set it in Azure portal:

[image]

Here is a demo of how to upload file to blob using javascript:

```
var blobUri = 'https://' + 'STORAGE_ACCOUNT' + '.blob.core.windows.net';
var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, 'SAS_TOKEN');
// If one file has been selected in the HTML file input element
var file = document.getElementById('fileinput').files[0];

var customBlockSize = file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32 ? 1024 * 1024 * 4 : 1024 * 512;
blobService.singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes = customBlockSize;

var finishedOrError = false;
var speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('mycontainer', 
file.name, file, {blockSize : customBlockSize}, function(error, result, response) {
    finishedOrError = true;
    if (error) {
        // Upload blob failed
    } else {
        // Upload successfully
    }
});
refreshProgress();
```

More information for your reference:
[Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library Sample for Blob Operations](https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html)

Comment: when I run the code I got this error msg: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createBlobServiceWithSas' of undefined`

Comment: @ZahooriNazo I didn't meet this error. Did you use the right SDK?  I downloaded at: https://aka.ms/downloadazurestoragejs

Comment: what is the purpose of it? Is it the same installing the library via npm?

Comment: @ZahooriNazo It may not be the same version. At lease, i have tested and it worked.

Comment: Amm, I found bundle folder, how can I attach these .js files to my code .. I am using VueJs .. only I should add them to any file like assets them importing them from the path?

Comment: actually I am installing Azure via npm then I add this line to use it `var AzureStorage = require('azure-storage');`

Comment: @ZahooriNazo i am not familiar with Vue, if you are using it on a web page, we can load these js files via jQuery or other js code. For example: document.writeln("<script src=\"/...xxx../azure-storage.blob.js\"></script>");

Comment: Do I need for all .js file or only for blob?

Comment: @ZahooriNazo if you only use blob, need only for blob

Comment: @ZahooriNazo If my answer is helpful, you can mark it as answer to help other community members find the helpful information quickly, thanks.

Comment: I don't know, it not work with me .. error msg: `AzureStorage not defined`.